# how to require different gems with the same name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am interested in making an application that requires me to require a gmail gem for ruby.
Right now there are 2 gems:

https://github.com/dcparker/ruby-gmail

https://github.com/nu7hatch/gmail

Both gems have the same require name, ie: gmail
The second one is much clear but there is a problem with one of its method. This method works well in the first gem (link). So I was thinking maybe I could require the first one for just that method. Is it possible to do so, how?

Comment: I doubt you’ll be able to use both these gems together. One defines `class Gmail` and the other defines `module Gmail`. You can’t have a class and a module with the same name. Even if both were a class or both were a module (so that you could require both files) you would be very lucky for them both to work together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others answers and comments have said, you cannot simply require both gems as they are.

However, given that both are hosted on GitHub, you could fork one of them and rename the offending classes. So long as your renaming is consistent within the gem you could use your fork within your Gemfile

Of course, you wouldn't be easily able to rebase changes onto your fork easily but if you really must use both gems this might be a compromise that you are happy with.

Answer (score -1):

You could add the following to your Gemfile:

```
gem 'gmail', :git => "git://github.com/dcparker/ruby-gmail", :branch => "master"
gem 'gmail', :git => "git://github.com/nu7hatch/gmail", :branch => "master"
```

Comment: This won’t work. You will get the error “You cannot specify the same gem twice coming from different sources.”

Comment: Is there any way I can create an alias? Like alias the first gem to g1 and the second to g2 or something like this.